# How to use in Kubernetes, an image from a private registry hosted in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have followed successfully this tutorial in order to create a private docker registry hosted in Kubernetes:
https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/devops/private-docker-registry

I've called my private registry `registro`, and the IP address of the service is: 10.43.48.208

With kaniko, I've gathered to push an `alpine` image to my registry in other to test.

I've created a secret in order to authenticate with the registry:

```
kubectl create secret generic cred-reg \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=./config.json \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Then:

```
kubectl edit serviceaccounts default
```

and added:

```
imagePullSecrets:
- name: cred-reg
```

Now I want to use that image in a pod.

```
kubectl run -ti --rm -q test --image=registro:5000/alpine
```

The result is this:

```
Failed to pull image "registro:5000/alpine": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registro:5000/alpine:latest": failed to resolve reference "registro:5000/alpine:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registro:5000/v2/alpine/manifests/latest": dial tcp: lookup registro on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving
```

It also fails:

```
kubectl run -ti --rm -q test --image=registro:5000/alpine --overrides='{ "spec": { "template": { "spec": { "imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "cred-reg"}] } } } }'
```

How can I avoid this error?

What is the IP address `127.0.0.53` about?

`registro:5000` is using a self-signed certificate.
How do I configure the Kubernetes cluster to accept this certificate?

Related questions:

- [Kubernetes not pulling image from private registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366046/kubernetes-not-pulling-image-from-private-registry)

**UPDATE 1**:

With:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/registro 5000:5000
```

and placed this line in my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 registro
```

and copy my self-signed certificate to: `/etc/docker/certs.d/registro:5000/ca.crt`, I can do successfully:

```
$ docker login https://registro:5000
$ docker run -ti --rm registro:5000/alpine
```

but I can't still access from kubernetes:

```
Failed to pull image "registro:5000/alpine": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "registro:5000/alpine:latest": failed to resolve reference "registro:5000/alpine:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registro:5000/v2/alpine/manifests/latest": EOF
```

I've tried with `curl` and it does work:

```
curl https://registro:5000/v2/alpine/manifests/latest -u myuser:mypassword
```

Comment: Looks like a **DNS issue preventing image pull**. To have a successful connection, you must always meet DNS, routing and firewall requirements.

Comment: If the cluster's nodes do not have external IP addresses themselves, which is the case of a private cluster, you will need to enable private access on the subnet used by the cluster. you can enable private access explicitly; or if you configure certain resources without external IP addresses to create outbound connections to the internet (used for internet egress), we turn private  access implicitly.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy, that's true, my private registry doesn't have access outside Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a **DNS issue preventing image pull**. To have a successful connection, **you must always meet DNS, routing and firewall requirements**. If the cluster's nodes do not have external IP addresses themselves, which is the case of a private cluster, you will need to enable private access on the subnet used by the cluster.  You can enable private access explicitly; or if you configure certain resources without external IP addresses to create outbound connections to the internet (used for internet egress), we can turn private access implicitly.